# possible put Ubuntu 18.04 Server to sleep with rtcwake and wake it up with Wake on Lan

Tags: server, wakeonlan

I recently got a HP Z420 with 8 cores and 32 GB memory, and set it up as a Ubuntu 18.04 server. Since it consumes a lot of power, I now use [rtcwake](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/rtcwake.8.html) to put it to sleep at 11 PM each night.

Since I rarely access it during the week day except occasionally login remotely to experiment with VBox VMs, docker containers and docker machines, etc., I'd like to keep it in sleep to memory mode and wake it up only remotely using wake-on-lan when I need to access it.

Is such an arrangement possible?

Comment: If you have another computer connected to it by LAN (Ethernet) cable you can use it to send the wake on LAN signal. A Raspberry Pi will do.

Comment: You don't need `rtcwake`. Just use `sudo shutdown`

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, I use a Respberry Pi as point of entry in my home network with 2-factor authentication so I can login securely when I'm traveling. I do need to use rtcwake to mem so my programs won't quit. Docker containers always quit when I rtcwake to disk.

Answer (score 3):

## Completely shutdown Ubuntu and wake it up remotely

### Completely shutdown the server

**This solution is different from the question as it shuts down the server completely.** It does not put it to sleep / suspend or hibernate.

To shutdown the Ubuntu 18.04 the following has to be true:

- The server must have `ssh` access from another (local) computer.

I use the following command to shutdown the server from the local computer:

```
ssh -t server.address "sudo /sbin/shutdown -h +1"
```

where server.address is either the IP address of the server or its domain name. The `-h` option powers the server off. The `+1` option is a one minute delay.

### Wake on Lan from the Raspberry Pi

Install `etherwake` in the Raspberry Pi. Make sure the Pi and the Ubuntu server are connected by Ethernet cables.

On the Ubuntu server find out the MAC address of the LAN port with the command:

```
ifconfig
```

It will look something like:

```
ether AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF   txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Use the following command from the Pi:

```
sudo etherwake -i eth0 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

where `eth0` is the Ethernet port of Pi, and `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` is the MAC address of the Ethernet port of the Ubuntu server.

I wrote a small script to save some typing in the Pi:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wake.sh

if ping -c 1 10.42.0.1 &> /dev/null
then
  echo "Server is ON already!"
else
  echo "Turning Server ON now."
  etherwake -i eth0 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
fi
```

where 10.42.0.1 is the IP address of the Ubuntu server. To use this script:

1. Save the script on the Pi with the name wake.sh in Pi's Home folder.
2. Edit the IP address and the MAC address of the Ubuntu server in the saved script.
3. Make the script executable.

Finally, call the script with:

```
sudo ./wake.sh
```

Hope this helps